# How should a Windows Service return information from a custom command

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-services

I have a windows service running as part of my application.

If I wish to communicate with it via the service handle I can issue custom commands (eg, 'start worker'). Ultimately, this will be a call to the Win32 [ControlService()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682108.aspx) function. What is the best way to return a block of data from such a command?

Specifically, I want to return a 'default URL' (ie a string) my service will respond on via other protocols like http.

A solution that is straightforward to implement in a C# (.net 2.0) service would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay with .net 2.0, use remoting.  Let windows handle the ControlService calls (for starting/stopping/pausing your service).  When you want your app to connect, establish a remoting connection to your service.  Works great.

Alternatives:
If you can move up to .net 3.5, you could use WCF instead of remoting.

You could use low-level communications (pipes and sockets), but really, remoting should be easier and work very well -- and it's supported in .net 2.0.

Comment: My brief scan of the remoting docs suggests that it is exposed to the network, with all the security implications of that. I only need a solution which works on the local machine.

Comment: @John McAleely
I believe that you can use the InterprocessCommunication channel: System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc if you want to ensure that only local processes can access your remotable objects.

Comment: Ah, yes - that looks ideal. I missed the fact it didn't use the network on my first read of the documentation.

Comment: @JohnMcAleely please tick on "Click this answer as accepted", is more easy for everyone that looks on the question. Also you have a rate of 55% accepted rate. If you accept answer, people will be more considerated when you ask for something. Too much people doesn't answer to a profile like yours

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into WCF?  You'd have to go to .NET 3.0 or above, but you can easily configure your services to run over TCP/IP, or HTTP, etc.